# Не могу правильно воспользоватся setInterval

Tags: javascript, функции, while, setinterval

```js
let i = 0
let t = 0
(function ab() {
  while (i < 61) {
    i++
    console.log(t + ":" + i)
    if (i >= 59) {
      i = 0
      t++
      console.log(t + ":" + i);
    }
  }
})
```

Вот исходный код.Хотел сделать секундомер
main.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: 0 is not a function
    at main.js:151
Вот ошибка.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А где вы тут вызываете seInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы точки с запятыми не ставите, потому что пиксели экономите?

```js
let i = 0;
let t = 0;

function ab() {
  console.clear();
  i++;
  if (i > 59) {
    i = 0;
    t++;
  }
  console.log(t + ":" + i);
}
setInterval(ab, 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но код так и не заработал.

Comment: @user380882 Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @user380882 Какой код не заработал? Вы понимаете, что мне сквозь монитор плохо видно, что у Вас на экране?

Comment: setInterval(ab,1000)
Вопрос был в том что я не могу сделать так чтобы консоль не превращалась в безумие, а был таймер

Comment: @user380882 Нет, вопрос был не в этом.

Comment: ПРОЧИТАЙ ЗАГЛАВЬЕ

Comment: Не могу правильно воспользоватся setInterval

Comment: @user380882 В Вашем коде нет вызовов `setInterval`.

Comment: Я просто забыл вставить его туда

Comment: let i = 0;
let t = 0;
function ab() {
  while (i < 61) {
    i++;
    console.log(t + ":" + i);
    if (i >= 59) {
      i = 0;
      t++;
      console.log(t + ":" + i);
    }
  }
}
setInterval(ab,1000)

Comment: вот код, попробуйте вставить его себе

Comment: и протестируйте

Comment: @user380882 Под вопросом - ссылка "править".

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает

Comment: @user380882 Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: > Вы точки с запятыми не ставите, потому что пиксели экономите? ++++++++